# If $ f$ is holomorphic in a rectangle then if it's smaller than its real part it's the $0$ function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function, on $G=\{x+yi\mid 0<x<1 \text{ and } 0<y<1\}$ and $|f(z)|\leq \operatorname{Re}(z)$ then $f(z)=0$.

I thought about uniqueness but all the zeros are outside $G$. Another approach was to try take a power series, but I wasn't able to find something interesting.

Another thought, why not taking $cl(G)$, and then according to uniqueness it will be  the 0 function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the Schwarz reflection principle: Define
$$
 g(z) = f(z) f(iz+1)f(-z+1+i)f(-iz+i)
$$
and then show that

- $g$ is well-defined in $G$.
- $\lim_{z \to \zeta} g(z) = 0$ for all $\zeta \in \partial G$.
- $g$ is identically zero in $G$.
- $f$ is identically zero in $G$.

The idea is to translate and rotate the argument of $f$ in a way that each of the four edges of $G$ is mapped to the segment on the imaginary axis, where the limiting values of $f$ are known to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with taking $f$ on $cl(G)$:

1. How to define $f$ on $cl(G)$?
2. A function is holomorphic only on open sets, so we need to extend $f$ not only to $cl(G)$ but to something bigger, in order to apply the uniqueness theorem.

It turns out that this difficulties can be overcome, if instead than $cl(G)$ we take a slightly different set:

Extend the function to be $0$ on $\{x+iy:x=0;y\in (0,1)\}$. It is clearly a continuous function on its extended domain, by the requirement that $|f(z)|\le |\Re(z)|$, and so one can apply Schwarz's reflection principle to define an extension $\hat{f}$of $f$on $\{x+iy; x\in(-1,1);y\in(0,1)\}$. By the identity principle, $\hat{f}\equiv 0$, and the result follows.

Comment: This is the correct solution.